# Matching Font Size of SVG with Regular Text in a Web Browser

Tags: svg, fonts

I am trying to get the font size of my svg file to match the font size of my regular text. I have managed to get the fonts themselves to match, both are using Open Sans by Steve Matteson however the sizing is different. My svg file consistently renders slight larger font than my regular text.

When I created the svg file (in Inkscape) I set the font size to 22.4px; I have also set the font size of my regular text to 22.4px. I have done some research on this and realize that svgs are quite complicated to render and that browsers have many default stylings, but I have not been able to hone in on what exactly causes this discrepancy in font size. (I have tried a browser reset code, this did not help; the problem remained exactly as it did without the reset).

Here is a screen shot comparing the regular text on top with the svg underneath. You can see the svg is slightly larger in font size (this is most visible when comparing the number "1" in the text vs the svg.

[image: Comparison of font size between text and svg]

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Font Comparison Test</title>
    <!-- Open Sans font by Steve Matteson -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">  
  </head>

<body>

  <p>
   Einige suchen dieselbe in der fortlaufenden Zahlenreihe
    von 1 bis 16 und legen den Gliedern dieser Reihe die Töne
    auf folgende Weise unter :

  </p>
  
 <!-- First graph, series 1 - 16 -->
    <img src="svg/1.1 English series 1 - 16.svg" style="width: auto; height: auto;">

</body>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  background-color: #162e2e;
  color: #dfddfe; /* Font colour */
  font-size: 22.4px; /* 1.4  = 22.4 px? */
  font-weight: 400; /* important for font styling */

}
```

SVG:

```
<svg

width="167mm"
height="17mm"
viewBox="0 0 167 17"
version="1.1"
id="svg127"

<g
inkscape:label="Layer 1"
inkscape:groupmode="layer"
id="layer1"
transform="translate(-17.407795,-14.122843)">
<text
   xml:space="preserve"
   style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:7.90222216px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Open Sans Condensed';-inkscape-font-specification:'Open Sans Condensed, ';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#dfddfe;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332" 
   x="18.06776"
   y="21.276409"
   id="text4998-2-0"><tspan
     sodipodi:role="line"
     x="18.06776"
     y="21.276409"
     style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-family:'Open Sans Condensed';-inkscape-font-specification:'Times New Roman, ';stroke-width:0.26458332"
     id="tspan5000-5-1">1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16</tspan></text>
```

Comment: Share your actual SVG code here and someone may be able to help you. It's much more difficult to control SVG behavior in an img tag so the answer will most likely involve inlining your SVG.

Comment: I just attempted to do that, the forum will not let me post the entire SVG code as it is about 80 000 characters long (just for the one svg file above). Is there a certain portion of the code I should isolate?

Comment: You can just do one <text> element inside the svg tag with the viewBox and any other attributes.

Comment: Can you post the SVG start tag and it's attributes, like: <svg .....>. I think that browsers render text in HTML and text in SVG differently, but there could be a slight difference between the size of the "container" and the SVG document.

Comment: I've added what I hope is the relevant part of the svg. I've included the viewbox, and the section of text which styles the first row of numbers from 1 to 16.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. solved by setting the svg width and height to "1em"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer works perfectly for me. Set the svg width and height to "1em" in the html, and then I set them programmitcally to the size I want them. Result: the text inside my svg shows exactly the same scale as outside it.